# Avoid creating onMessage function per WS client

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Following `ws`'s instructions to create a WebSocket server:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

  ws.send('something');
});
```

An onMessage callback named `incoming` is created for every client, am I right?

Imagine having two million clients. This code would create two million functions. Is there a way to avoid this? Something like this would be wonderful:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('message', function incoming(ws, message) {
  // Access to ws object
  console.log('received: %s', message);
});
```

Comment: I think you are over reacting....

Comment: So was I wrong when saying it creates a function for every client?

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```html
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

function handleMessage(message) {
  console.log('received: %s', message); 
}

wss.on('message', handleMessage);
```

Comment: The event `message` is not emitted by `WebSocket.Server`

Comment: + the code isn't correct, it should be `wss.on('message', handleMessage);`

Comment: Fair enough.  Code changed.